# What's This Blue Cube Icon in the View Controller Scene Graph

Tags: xcode

New to XCode, and trying to get my head around the various things in this IDE. So my question is, what are the two blue cube thingys which I've circled in the image below?

This screenshot is taken from XCode 7, in case that matters.

[image: Blue Cube Thingys]

[image: Now showing the storyboard]

Comment: Do you have a picture of your view controller?

Comment: Seems like NSObject.

Comment: NSObject sounds awfully generic. Adding a new screenshot now...

Comment: Whats it say about it in the attribute editor in the right hand pane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's static `Section` of `UITableView`

[image: 4 Sections as you see]